# Perl, get list of interfaces without special modules

Tags: perl, networking, interface

I'm writing a Perl script for a webfront on vnstat/vnstati. I'm not sure how to build a list of interfaces without any special modules like `Net::Interface` or `OS::Interface`

Here is how I'm doing it in bash:

```
ip addr show|grep "^[0-9]:"|grep -e "state UP"|cut -d':' -f2
```

Which returns wlan1, but I need to have it create an array within Perl. Here is what I have so far:

```
my @graphs = (
        { interface => 'eth0' },
        { interface => 'venet0' },
);
```

That's the "default" but some of my machines have more then 1 and I don't want to customize it every time I build a new test server.

Comment: Why are you avoiding modules that would do the job for you?

Comment: the project im working on, is very limited for space. 600MB is all i have to work with. and 480MB of that is just the system.

Comment: but the modules are comparatively tiny...

Comment: @Borodin: that's just the one .pm file; all three and the .so total 308k on my system (but the point remains)

Answer (score 0):

What's the question? How to execute and capture the output of that shell command?

```
my $output = `...command...`;
```

Comment: i was going to do that..but im not quite sure how to parse it into the @graphs array.